# Can particular object be detected and extracted from RAM?

Tags: forensics, programming

I was Googling for a while now, and I don't seem to find what I am looking for.

Imagine I have a programm running (for example some random image generator, perhaps captcha) and I have a background process with NO GUI but with Full permission running on the same machine. I want the second process to capture the location of the Image object (assuming I know the object type and maybe even approximate size) and get its contents into a local process variable. Is it possible to do? I know the reading RAM part is possible (Cheat Engine does that easily), but actuall task of detecting an object of certain type which is located in a certain process's memory. Will knowing the variable name help me? Is there a list with addresses of all variables in memory somewhere?

Comment: Under what operating system? From a security perspective, the answer is generally yes as long as the other program has sufficient privileges. But practically speaking, looking for the image in memory is very unlikely to be the simplest way of solving your problem. The easiest way would be to make the image generator dump the image into a file. If you really can't do that, you *can* arrange to grab it from the display, whether or not your capture program itself has a GUI. I suggest asking on [so], **stating your end goal (with the OS, program, etc.)** and not the wrong path you've started on.

Comment: @Gilles Thanks. I was thinking of the issue from the security side of view, as the task I am trying to acomplish is tricker than extracting an image from the Third-party program. I am trying to understand if system (any in general, Windows in specific) keeps a list of variables (index) somewhere in the memory and if it (segment of memory with index) is readable to the process. I will try asking on Stack Overflow from programming side of view as well.

Comment: There is no "list with address of variables in memory". Some programs, depending on their programming language, *may* have a list of some kind, but it generally isn't connected with variable *names* that, in compiled languages, usually don't even exist anyway. You can recognize the image from its format, though, if you know what you're looking for and its storage layout in the target program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just a developer with a security interest, but:

It seems like one way to answer your question is the technique of File / Memory Carving.

Looking through the raw memory or disk for content (such as images or documents etc).

It is a forensics technique, sort of like brute force searching memory for documents.

[File Carving - Includes a lot of related terminology](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/File_Carving)

[File Carving Tools (start with a memory image)](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Tools%3aData_Recovery#Carving)